# Why does jkmwpkl.gov.my only look like it should on Chrome for Windows?

Tags: google-chrome

1. Go to [jkmwpkl.gov.my](http://www.jkmwpkl.gov.my/) on Chrome for Ubuntu 13.10
2. Note that the page does not display correctly
3. Go to [jkmwpkl.gov.my](http://www.jkmwpkl.gov.my/) on Chrome for Windows 7
4. Note that it DOES display correctly.

So why the discrepancy?

This is what it looks like on 13.10
[image]

This is what it should look like
[image]

Comment: Could you add screen-shots?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: What is it *supposed* to look like? Note that not all of us have quick access to Windows.

Comment: OK added Windows 7 screenshot

Comment: This question might be better in WebMasters or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be the type of font in the title.

If you disable the fonts in the "#jsddm li" css selector (line 139 of style.css) you will get the same error on Windows. I suggest you either include the fonts on the site or use a more universal font for the title.

Here is how it looks when I add the Ubuntu font on that specific line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm not sure what I can do at this end, this site does not belong to me, it's a government site. 

What can I do client-side to make this page display correctly? thanks.

Comment: I would recommend userscripts from tampermonkey or greasemonkey.

Comment: Consider using the [Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/)